# OpenCV 3.1 warning and crash in usage of UMat

Tags: c++, opencv, mat

I'm new in using OpenCV. I use c++ in visual studio 2013 and opencv 3.1 . I want to calculate Canny edges and here is my code:

```
UMat getImage()
{
    return imread("...\\myPic.jpg").getUMat(ACCESS_FAST);
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    UMat u;
    u = getImage();

    cv::Canny(u, u, 100, 50);

    namedWindow("Display window", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);// Create a window for display.
    imshow("Display window", u);

    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

I can't see the result or any image. Instead of it, I see this window:
[image]

What is wrong?
*I note that I can see my pic in case of using `Mat` instance.*

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems with the code you wrote.

1) imshow will not properly display your image without a slight pause. You need to add function waitkey(0) after imshow for the image to properly show the result.

2) When handling UMat variables, it is better to receive and return the reference matrix instead of returning the entire matrix since the UMat memory is not always in the CPU space.
Here is how your code should look like

```
void getImage(cv::OutputArray u)
{
    cv::imread("...\\myPic.jpg").getUMat(cv::ACCESS_FAST).copyTo(u);
}

  int main(int argc, const char** argv)
    {
        cv::UMat u;
        getImage(u);

        cv::Canny(u, u, 100, 50);

        cv::namedWindow("Display window", cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);// Create a window for display.
        cv::imshow("Display window", u);
        cv::waitKey(0);
        getchar();

        return 0;
    }
```

Good luck